# Why do arrays still point to the first element when & is infront of it

Tags: arrays, c

In the C standard it says:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.

So, why when you declare `&array` it still points to the first element if it isn't supposed to be a pointer type?

Comment: `&array` points to the start of the array, which also happens to be the address of the first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual *value* (i.e. memory address) of an `&array` expression will be the same as the address of the first element of `array` – but the ***type*** of the expression will *not be converted to* "pointer-to-element-type"; rather, it will remain as "pointer-to-array".

The difference will become apparent if you start doing pointer arithmetic on the address value:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int* p = arr + 1; // p will point to the second element
    int* q = (int*)(&arr + 1); // q will point past the end of the array
    //               ^ This has type "pointer to int[4]"
    // Spot the difference ...
    printf("%p %p\n", (void*)(arr), (void*)(arr + 1));
    printf("%p %p\n", (void*)(&arr), (void*)(&arr + 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's a pointer to an array, and it gives the value of the first address, does that mean the array is inherently the address

Comment: @Paralax01 No. Arrays are *not* pointers; they just "decay" into pointers to their first element in most expressions (the exceptions being those listed in the citation from the Standard you posted).

Comment: @Adrain Mole so why when it isn't decaying to a pointer to its first element, it still points to the array first element

Comment: In `&array`, there is no need for any decay. You are *explicitly* making a pointer expression when you use the `&` operator. Also, although I don't think the word, "decay," is used in the Standard, it is widely used because the pointer has lost information (the size of the array). In the case of `&array`, that size isn't lost - the pointed-to type includes the array size.

Comment: If I have a row of houses in a street, the location of the first house is the same as the location of the whole row. Same with arrays (of integers or of houses).